# Configure Jenkins update channel for stable release in Groovy script?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-cli

I want to script my Jenkins installation. I use always use the "stable" release of Jenkins (currently : 2.121.3), but I noticed that when I install the stable release, the update website (in admin > plugin > advance) is setted to "https://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.json" which is not the stable release. I have to change this setting to "http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/stable/update-center.json".

I want to do it automatically, by script. I know I can change this setting in the `/var/lib/jenkins/hudson.model.UpdateCenter.xml` file, but I prefere to use a Groovy script to do this.

But I cant find a way to change this settings in  Groovy scriptbecause i'm not aware of the Jenkins/Hudson data model neither the Groovy syntax, I dont know how to change and save the setting.

Comment: I could not find a better way to do this. After basic installation, i replace the `/var/lib/jenkins/hudson.model.UpdateCenter.xml` config file with this content : `<?xml version='1.1' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<sites>
  <site>
    <id>default</id>
    <url>https://updates.jenkins.io/stable/update-center.json</url>
  </site>
</sites>
`

Answer (score 2):

I was also searching for something like this, I just solved this using groovy, hope this helps anyone else as well.

```js
import hudson.model.UpdateCenter;
import hudson.model.UpdateSite;
import hudson.util.PersistedList;
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

site = "http://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.json"; // TBD: update as necessary
PersistedList < UpdateSite > sites = Jenkins.getInstance().getUpdateCenter().getSites();
for (UpdateSite s: sites) {
  if (s.getId().equals(UpdateCenter.ID_DEFAULT))
    sites.remove(s);
}
sites.add(new UpdateSite(UpdateCenter.ID_DEFAULT, site));
```

Answer (score 1):

As for the current Jenkins core API version (>2.16X),

The [UpdateCenter Javadoc](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/UpdateCenter.html) and [UpdateSite Javadoc](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/UpdateSite.html) do not display any method that allows to either add or update the update site.

The [UpdateCenter Class](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/model/UpdateCenter.java) source code confirms that the values of the update sites are actually loaded (I suppose at the start of Jenkins) with no possibility to alter the lists afterwards.

So I guess the only way to set a custom update site is to have a custom update site is to feed Jenkins with a custom `hudson.model.UpdateCenter.xml` at the start.

Here're a couple of observations that I made (please confirm or invalidate in the comments below, as I'm not 100% sure about these):

- the custom update site must have id `default`
- discovery of plugins seems to fail at first start. Jenkins must be re-started in order to discover plugins.